# python find path

Tags: python

Uninformed search to find within a black and white image a path that connects the upper left corner of the image with the lower right corner, passing only black pixels with depth search (DFS), my program already opens the image with `opencv` and if I put a coordinate, it tells me if the pixel is black or not but idk how to do the rest.
Also I have to create an image with the found path, making an image that paints a pixel for each item in the successor list.

Answer (score 4):

Lets read image

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)
```

Now, we can build a graph using this image and using path finding algorithms, we can get path between two nodes.

```
from itertools import product, chain
import math
import mtplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx


h, w = im.shape. # Get height and width of image

# Add only those nodes which are black to graph
nodes = [(i, j) for (i, j) in product(range(h), range(w)) if im[i, j] == 0]
g = nx.Graph(nodes)

# For each node there can be 8 neighbours, if you consider diagonal as well.
def get_neighbors(node):
    box_coords = product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1])
    nns = []
    for coord in box_coords:
        if coord[0] != coord[1]:
            nn = (node[0] - coord[0], node[1] - coord[1])
            nns.append(nn)
    return nns

# A point will be a neighbour if it is black as well and is in image bounds
neighbors = list(chain.from_iterable([[(node, ng_node, 1) for ng_node in  get_neighbors(node) if (im[node] == 0) and (0 < ng_node[0] < h) and (0 < ng_node[1] , w)] for node in nodes]))

g.add_weighted_edges_from(neighbors)

# In image loaded above (0, 0) is top left point. To keep things little more generic. I select point closest to (0, 0) as start and furthest as end.

min_pt = min(nodes, key=lambda x: math.hypot(x[0], x[1]))
max_pt = max(nodes, key=lambda x: math.hypot(x[0], x[1]))

# Now we can just use networkx to find path between two points
path = nx.shortest_path(g, source=min_pt, target=max_pt)

# Get new image with only shortest path
im2 = 255*np.ones_like(im)
for pt in path:
    im2[pt] = 0
cv2.imwrite('image_path.png', im2)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(im2, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the great help :) only one question I have an error in this line "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" and in this one too ""plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10)), do I have to import more libraries? import numpy as np?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt?

Comment: ohh thank you I already added those two libraries but nothing appears on the screen, will be my IDE?

Comment: you can save the image `cv2.imwrite('im2.png', im2)` and open using any image application. If you are running this in jupyter notebook, it would show inline image.

Comment: Cool! Happy to help.